# Save video to a custom Album using Photos Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, photosframework

I want to save a video that is taken using a custom camera to a particular album say `NewAlbum` in the `Photos Library` using the `Photos Framework`.
I have found some answers but they referred to use of `ALAssetsLibrary` which is deprecated now.

Kindly let me know if you need any more details, also rectify me if I missed something.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution To [create a PHAsset from an Video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36419456/5227674):

**Code Block 1:**

```
PhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(/*Your url here*/)
    placeholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    identifier = placeholder.localIdentifier
}, completionHandler: {
    success, error in 
    /* 
       Fetch Asset with the identifier here
       after that, add the PHAsset into an album
    */
    newAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier], options: nil).firstObject
}
```

you can add the `PHAsset` with the following snippet:

**Code Block 2:**

```
// Consider we have a known localIdentifier for a specific PHAssetCollection defined as -> let collectionIdentifier: String
guard let collection: PHAssetCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [collectionIdentifier], options: nil).fistObject else {
   // handle Error
   return
}
PhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

    guard let addAssetRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: collection) else { return }

    addAssetRequest.addAssets([newAsset] as NSArray)
}, completionHandler: {
    success, error in
    //handle error or stuff you want to do after that here
})
```

**EDIT Example for create a `PHAssetCollection`**

In this case, I fetched the create `PHAssetCollection` after it was created in the `performChanges(_:,completionHandler:)` closure and put it in the `@escaping` closure of that function.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({

        let createRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: name)
        placeHolderIdentifier = createRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection.localIdentifier

    }, completionHandler: {
        success, error in
        if success {
            var createdCollection: PHAssetCollection? = nil
            if placeHolderIdentifier != nil {
                createdCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeHolderIdentifier!], options: nil).firstObject
            }
            completion(success, createdCollection as? T)
        } else {
            LogError("\(error)")
            completion(success, nil)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @Ankit Kumar Gupta so did it worked? Or are you still struggeling with sth?

Comment: Sorry @Marcel got some other priorities this week. Will surely test it and let you know in the next one.

Comment: no problem, just wanted to know if you need additional informations.

Comment: how to create `PHAssetCollection` ?

Comment: @user25 You could use the `PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest` for that it has the function `creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle:)` You have to initialize that in the `performChanges(_:completionHandler:)` closure. When you need it in the `completionHandler` right after the `performChanges` closure you need to create a PlaceHolder. I will update my Answer with an example of that.

Comment: @MarcelT how can I move video file mp4 (`URL`) from documents to a specific album in Photos? I already created `PHAssetCollection`

Comment: @user25 When You see the first code block you see the `PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(/*Your url here*/)` Like in the example you need to get the placeholder Identifier. In the Completion Handler fetch the created asset with `PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier], options: nil).firstObject` where `identifier` is the placeholder Identifier and add the Asset like it is mentioned in the second code block. I will mark the Blocks with a Bold Text now :)

Comment: @MarcelT thank you so much! It worked. Now I can record videos to documents and when recording is finished move them to a specific album in Photos. Now I'm going to solve my next task - open **Photos** app from my app for a specific album (`PHAssetCollection`), I don't if it's possible but I'll try to Google:)

Comment: @user25 good luck with that one, i would start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106757/5227674) with your search, it looks promising, I haven't done anything like this before.

Comment: @MarcelT what should I paste instead of it`/*your specific album here as PHAssetCollection*/` in the second block?

Comment: @HackerMane that would be a PHAssetCollection, which is a Album where you want to add the PHAsset to. You can fetch a existing PHAssetCollection with one of its methods [Doku](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollection)

Comment: @MarcelT, K, I've checked out the doc, I understand that I need to fetch PHAssetCollection, but how do I do that? Maybe You will edit your answer, because it has got to be full, please.

Comment: @HackerMane I could add that part for sure, but that really depends on the circumstances. I'll add a example where you have a given Identifier for a PHAssetCollection would that be enough?

Comment: @MarcelT, can you help, when I print my collection identifier, it shows that it's empty, as well as a local identifier, how do I write an identifier data in it?