# How to move video file to a specific album in Photos?

Tags: ios, swift

I can move video files to root in Photos, but I want to move it to a specific album (with `localIdentifier`)

function to move video file to Photos root (need to edit it to move to a specific album of Photos - localIdentifier)

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                print("performChanges")
                let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                options.shouldMoveFile = true

                let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()

                creationRequest.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: self._VideoFileURL, options: options)
            }, completionHandler: { success, error in
                if !success {
                    print("Could not save movie to photo library: \(String(describing: error))")
                } else {
                    print("Saved movie to photo library")
                }
            }
```

Comment: found solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669385/4548520 author updated it while I was writing to him

Answer (score -1):

Here is the method I used to check whether file already exists or not.

```
 static func isAlreadyExists(fileName:String) -> Bool {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(Constants.AppName).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path)){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }

}
```

Here is the code to save file to Specific folder

```
  static func createDirectory() -> URL {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let DocumentsDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(Constants.AppName)

    if !(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: DocumentsDirectory.path)){
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: DocumentsDirectory.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(" Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return DocumentsDirectory

}
```

Hope so it will work for you.

Comment: how can I use it for album in Photos? p.s. it's only part of my question, I also want to find out how to move file to a specific album in Photos (main part of my question)

Comment: p.s. I'm talking about Photos framework - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos