# Uploading Videos to Specific album in gallery of iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am getting this error while downloading the video to a specific album in Photo library of iPhone.

```
func saveImage(filePath: String) {

    if assetCollection == nil {
        return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
    }
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in

        if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ () -> Void in

                let createAssetRequest: PHAssetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(string: filePath)!)!
                createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset

            }) { (success, error) -> Void in

                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                if success {

                    //popup alert success
                }
                else {
                    //popup alert unsuccess
                }
            }
        }else {

        }
    })

}
```

I Expected Video saved successfully.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1

Comment: check the localized description of the error.

Comment: localized description is : The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669178/save-video-to-a-custom-album-using-photos-framework-in-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1 ,

Comment: Still same "error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)). 
Finally I noticed you have to add an extension to the (temporary) filename. In my case adding ".mp4" solved this.